# Increase the number of posts per page based on the number of ignored tags

Tags: feature-request, questions, ignored-tags, pagination, posts

Okay, we all know the issue.

No fixes are forthcoming.  Let the UI hide posts.  Fine.  Less work on the servers, we get it.

So, how about if I have, say, two hundred ignored tags, let me select, say, 200 posts per page?  It would be better than having 10 posts visible on the page as I do now.  Also, it would help with the issue of questions falling off the front page quicker than they can get answers.

Comment: This isn't an exact duplicate, since it has the conditional.

Comment: Gah, I got closed as exact dupe of *one of my own posts*.  That's some BS right there.  I am severely butthurt.

Comment: WHOA!  Abuse of mod powers!  Wat up!  (wasn't the first reopen vote, and if it gets closed again I won't reopen again.  Unless I'm really tipsy, not that I tipple or anything, I'm not admitting to something, so stop looking at me)

Comment: Also, not dupe; I'm asking for the number of posts to be linked to the number of ignore tags, which is **NOT** part of either related posts.  In fact, I think relating ignored tags to available posts-per-page is a very good compromise between server side efficiency and user friendliness.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather the user set it explicitly.

In my experience the kind of fuzzy math you suggest would lead to folks reporting bugs (that aren't), tests that are hard and complex and a lot of opinions and discussion on the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think having an algorithm to try to guess how many posts you should have per page based on the number of ignored tags is a good idea. Actually, I don't see the relationship between number of ignored tags and number of posts you'd like to have per page: I think you're more likely to want like 200 posts per page **regardless** of how many tags you ignored, no?

But to expand on your idea, it would be nice for the users to be able to decide a fixed number of posts per page, taking into account the ignored tags. And it would be useful to be able to set this number per section: I may want 200 posts on the same page for new questions, but on /review for example I probably don't want as many, maybe closer to 30 as the default setting.